# JSP file upload not being passed to Controller in GAE

Tags: java, jsp, google-app-engine, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I know it has been asked multiple times but I am unable to get my problem fixed.

Bean class

```
@Component
@Scope("prorotype")
public class NotesData {
    //with getters/setters
    String college;
    String topic;
    String subject;
    String description;
    MultipartFile file;

}
```

JSP

```
<form:form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" modelAttribute="notesData">
    <form:input path="file" name="file" type="file" />
    <form:input path="description" name="description" type="text" />
    <div>colleges</div>
    <form:select path="college" name="college">
        <c:forEach var="entry" items="${colleges}">
                <option value="${entry.key}">${entry.key}</option>
        </c:forEach>
    </form:select>
    <input type="Submit" value="Submit">
</form:form>
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String uploadFile(@ModelAttribute("notesData") NotesData nd, ModelMap model, BindingResult br, HttpServletRequest request) {
    //TODO: Check why modelAttribute is not working.
    System.out.println("Inside post " + nd);
    System.out.println(request.getParameterMap());
    model.addAttribute("subjects", getSubjects());
    model.addAttribute("colleges", getColleges());
    return "upload";
}
```

On submission of the form, request is coming to the controller but values are not coming up. Along with @ModelAttribute, I also passed **HttpServletRequest** but that is also coming out to be empty.

Problem seems to be with GAE and MultipartUpload incompatibility. I tried using GMultipart but then I keep on getting following exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItemHeadersSupport
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader.loadClass(IsolatedAppClassLoader.java:215)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.gmr.web.multipart.GFileItemFactory.createItem(GFileItemFactory.java:47)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:350)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(ServletFileUpload.java:126)
```

I have added following jars in the lib folder:

```
1. commons-fileuplaod-1.2
2. commons-io-2.0
3. gmultipart-0.4
```

What am I doing wrong? Any alternatives or solutions?

Comment: Multipart request handling needs to be properly configured. Check Spring and / or Servlet API documentation on that topic. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-multipart

Comment: Even If I remove file option, data is not passed to the controller.

Comment: `enctype="multipart/form-data"` is controlling request format. Servlet containers (before 3.0) can natively parse only `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. And even with 3.0 you need to do some configuration http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/servlets011.htm to enable multipart requests... I suggest to read though the Spring documentation about this topic.

Comment: I have added those configurations. Problem appears to be with GAE. Please check the updated question for the issue.

Comment: I don't have any experience on Google App Engine... upvoting the question to get attention from others.